# How to get a random single category name in get_posts()?

Tags: theme-development, query, get-posts

How can I get a random category name one at a time?? The post may have multiple category instead of a single category. I just want to show a single category name in the post grid loop.

```php
$home_blog_posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    =>  3
));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_post_categories` to get the categories from your posts. Then you can use `array_rand` to get one random category from that array.

Check out these links on how to use `wp_get_post_categories` and `array_rand` to suit your needs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: It works just like a charm. Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: You are very welcome, have a nice day!